# Shortcut to toggle between .h and .m files in xcode5

Tags: xcode, xcode5, trackpad

I was very comfortable using 3 finger swipe up or down gesture on a trackpad to toggle between prior versions of Xcode, However in `Xcode5` I don't find an easy gesture on trackpad to do so.

Have any one identified any easier shortcuts on trackpad to toggle between your .h and .m files in `Xcode5`?

Comment: I've only just begun using Xcode5, but I find that I often open an implementation file directly after opening its header, so I can just two-finger swipe back and forth between them, or further down the "stack." Perhaps I have not had enough time using it to need that specific feature though.

Comment: I know its swipe back and forth is to moving down/up the stack, but irrespective of my .m file being next in the stack to pop out next, I want it anytime. - Sure this was available in Xcode3 atleast.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`ctrl`+`cmd`+`up arrow`

Enjoy your extra productivity!

Comment: So Simple yet Powerful

Comment: this brings up the finder for me, what am i doing wrong?